# oauth_problem=signature_invalid

Tags: php, oauth

I'm using pecl oauth in php, it workds fine in plain php using localhost, and I was able to get the request token. But when I use it on a framework, it throws exception and gives me 
oauth_problem=signature_invalid.

this framework is being used on a virtual host. Any idea ?

(details can be found below as my comment)

Comment: not being clairvoyant, I'd need a LOT more info in order to have a clue what's going on.

Comment: here is the structure
here are the details ... 
my web root:

http://arfeen.local

http://pastebin.com/sV9L00hx (.htaccess)

http://pastebin.com/yCEHYxP3 (oauth.php) (framework Controller)

http://pastebin.com/1KKPdTKH (oauthprovider.php) (provider class)



http://arfeen.local/oauth/login (oauth client)

And I think rest of the thing you can understand once you understand the code.

Outside the framework it works fine but within framework I get "signature invalid" . thats why im also giving you ".htaccess" file ..

Answer (score 0):

Two of your three paste bins aren't working for me, but I'm also creating an OAuth provider myself and I ran into a problem with my keys.  How are you storing them in the database?

In my case, I was saving the SHA1 keys into `BINARY(20)` columns by calling the MYSQL function `UNHEX()` when I inserted them and then calling `HEX()` when I pulled them out[1].  The problem was that HEX and UNHEX return uppercase values, and when I was generating the SHA1 keys using the `sha1()` function they were lowercase[2].  Make sure they are the same case, because it will affect the signature.

[1] [Storing SHA1 hash values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614476/storing-sha1-hash-values-in-mysql) 
[2] http://us.php.net/sha1

Comment: Just saw how old this question was.  Whoops!

Comment: @Steve.. thanks for the reply. There was a problem in the framework i was using that time and I handed it over to the person who developed the framework. But thanks for your suggestion, will consider it in any future case of oAuth.