# Override SQL generated by CakePHP's field type mapping

Tags: cakephp

I was hoping to get Cake PHP 2.x's field type mapping to change password field from a salted SHA1 hash into a varchar field, to UNHEX('$hash') in SQL, so I can store the password in the binary(20) field.

For anyone questioning why I'm doing it this way:
[Storing SHA1 hash values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614476/storing-sha1-hash-values-in-mysql)

Currently I see no way around it than to do my own $this->User->query("INSERT INTO....");, and it would be nice to do it the cake way.

Any advise would be great!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = DboSource::expression('UNHEX('. $this->data[$this->alias]['password'].')');
    $this->data[$this->alias]['test'] = 'hello';
    }
    return true;
}
```