# Shorten sha1 hash for database storage for later retrieval?

Tags: php, sha

Is there a way I can shorten a sha1 hash to store in a database, and then upon retrieval perform a unshorten function on it to display the original?

I am not sure this is possible, my sha1 hashes are currently 40 characters long.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing SHA1 hash values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/614476/53114).

Comment: If you are using SHA1 to hash passwords, consider using something like SHA256 instead, since SHA1 is compromised. Also, why do you need to shorten the hash in the DB? Truncating hashes isn't always a safe operation...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It could only make your passwords less secure.

Comment: I am not using it to store passwords at all.

Comment: `pack('H', $asciiHash);` will convert your 40 byte ascii representation to a 20 byte binary one, and `unpack('Hascii', $binaryHash);` will convert it back again, but if you're really bothered about saving 20 bytes here and there I suggest you have more important things to worry about...

Comment: Haha and people downvote on the compromise of a security concern when my question has nothing to do with security I have a valid use for using sha1 and wanting to truncate the string

Comment: @DaveRandom I have a table of around 5million rows containing just sha1 hashes, I don't think I have anything to worry about, about wanting to save space.

Comment: @hadley fair enough - 20 bytes is as small as you will get without any loss of data (since SHA-1 is a 160-bit hash), you can actually get `sha1()` to return the binary version by passing `TRUE` as the second argument

Comment: You would need to convert your database fields to (assuming MySQL) `VARBINARY`, `BLOB` etc for storage

Comment: @hadley [Here's a little demo](http://codepad.org/yTQfMsKA)

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks this is awesome and has helped me understand alot :)