# SQL: SELECT binary value

Tags: mysql, binary

I have:

```
$token  = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

Then I'll insert it into the database using `unhex('$token')`. How do I select this value?

I've tried:

```
SELECT token FROM `name` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

If I echo it in it'll show as `0b7GÞ÷:‹xcÅ•½JAjdäáæ` rather than something like  `5dc012f007b7c4db7b9e076138fdd92fa1039530`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ - how about: you are using UNHEX in the first place? I mean, what for do you do that? And if you really think this is necessary - why haven't you read in the manual about what the "inverse" function to UNHEX is?

Comment: @CBroe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614476/storing-sha1-hash-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to store it with `UNHEX`, but you can `SELECT HEX(token)` to get back the original value.

Comment: I figured out moments ago I had to do "HEX(token) as token", leaving out the as token was causing an undefined index error. Thanks. :)