# is hex-encoding standard in MySQL

Tags: mysql, encoding

I was just asking myself if this is standard, because I was setting a column to Type "Char 40" to store a SHA1 value. Is this true? or do I have to pay more attention when I do this in case I work with other then my own mysql database.

Thanks

EDIT

the best possible answer is, that SHA1 just works that way. I thought it was returning 160 bits and some other config setting converted it into a 40 char string, but it always returns that 40 digit string. [see doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1)

Comment: `CHAR` in MySQL is a string type.  You can store any string characters in there.  It doesn't matter if it's hex or not.  `CHAR` isn't "hex-encoded".

Comment: a better question would be, why is sha1 always 40 characters long? yes, it's always stored like that , because a char is represented by a 4 bit, but why?

Comment: Because that's how it works.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Comment: Using `CHAR(40)` to store your SHA1 hashes is fine, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I just found this, it might help you more than I can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/614483

Comment: That post was actually the reason I started to think about it, I just need to know why a char is 4 bit, but thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA1 returns 40 characters, yes.